# Why do we have to import and then extend a JFrame, why cant we use it by just importing it?

Tags: java, swing, inheritance, import

In the code below, the JFrame has been imported first and then it is extended. what is the reason for extending it after it is already imported ? why cant we directly use it on importing it, like Scanner ?

```
    import java.awt.FlowLayout;
    import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
    import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
    import javax.swing.JFrame;
    import javax.swing.JButton;
    import javax.swing.Icon;
    import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
    import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

    public class tuna extends JFrame{

        private JButton reg;
        private JButton custom;

        public tuna(){
            super("The Title");
            setLayout(new FlowLayout());            

            reg = new JButton("reg Button");
            add(reg);

            Icon x = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("xxx.png"));
            Icon y = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("yyy.png"));

            custom = new JButton("custom button" , x);
            custom.setRolloverIcon(y);
            add(custom);

            handler thehandler = new handler();
            reg.addActionListener(thehandler);
            custom.addActionListener(thehandler);
        }

        public class handler implements ActionListener{

            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event){

                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, String.format("%s", event.getSource()));

            }
        }
}
```

thanks in advance !

Comment: don't to extend JFrame, create this Object as local variable

Comment: You don't have to extend `JFrame.` Your question is based on a false premiss.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you define the tuna class based on the JFrame object. You need to import the JFrame class first otherwise the JVM won't know what is a JFrame and thus won't be able to create the tuna class.

You should see what 'import' means in Java.

By the way, the first letter of a class should always be a capital letter. tuna should be called Tuna.

Answer (score 1):

Importing a class, is making it so you can use that class without needing to qualify the full name in the current class you are writing.

Extending a class is creating a new class that is a subclass of some other class. This will make your subclass inherit the attributes and methods of the superclass.

Btw, you don't need to extend JFrame.

Comment: i read the same thing when i tried to find it.. but what happens when we import it ? 
i know that instead of writing 
java.util.Scanner sc = new java.util.Scanner(System.in);, you can simply write Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

what functions do we get to use by just importing ??

Comment: When you import a package or a specific class you can instantiate (when possible) that same class and access its public methods